# Subtracting raster from number using Rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

How can I subtract a raster from a constant value using Rasterio?

I see many posts on how to subtract two rasters but not on subtracting a raster from a constant value.

What I have tried:

```
import rasterio as rio
with rio.open("final_elevation.tif", masked=True) as src:
   dem = src.read(1)
   # image_read_masked = np.ma.masked_array(dem, mask=(dem == -9999))
   depth = -dem + 100
```

The results will generate an incorrect output. For example, no data values are now 100 + 9999

An example raster is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/t/1m3ChJMGH1ynZPRD)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the mask to reset the nodata. Don't forget to *read* the data as masked, not when you *open* the dataset.

```
import rasterio as rio

with rio.open("final_flood_elevation.tif") as src:
   dem = src.read(1, masked=True)
   profile = src.profile

depth = 100 - dem
depth[depth.mask] = profile["nodata"]

with rio.open("final_flood_elevation_calc.tif", 'w', **profile) as dst:
   dst.write(depth, 1,)
```